# Uploading image from android to server using php

Tags: php, android, image, server

I'm trying to store images taken from Android Studio (from the user's gallery), and write the base64 encoded image-to-string using php to be stored on a webserver.

I have been looking at numerous tutorials that implments this in different ways. I chose to follow the one done with fopen() function, but it kept giving me a "no file or directory found" error.

Afterwards i tried writing the full path of the image directory in which i'll save the images in. The error changed into the error message i defined in the "else" part of the code, which is:

> {"error":true,"error_msg":"Unknown error occurred while creating the offer. Please try again."}

Here's the full code:

```
class create_offer_form {

private $conn;

// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'android_login_connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new android_login_connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

public function StoreOfferInfo($offerMname, $offerUname, $offerTitle, $offerText, $offerBranch, $offerDateTime, $offerMinPrice, $offerMaxPrice, $offerCategory, $offerImageURL) {


        $image_name = time()."_".rand().".jpeg" ;


        $decoded_string = base64_decode($offerImageURL);

        $path = 'AndroidUploadedImages/'.$image_name;

        $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

        $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
        fclose($file);

        if($is_written > 0) {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Image(Image) VALUES(?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $path);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            if($result){
                echo "success";
            }else{
                echo "failed";
            }

        }


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Offer(Offer_title, Offer_memberName, Offer_branch, Offer_text, Offer_image, Offer_DateTime, Offer_minPrice, Offer_maxPrice, Offer_category, Offer_Username) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $offerTitle, $offerMname, $offerBranch, $offerText, $offerImageURL, $offerDateTime, $offerMinPrice, $offerMaxPrice, $offerCategory, $offerUname);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Offer_title, Offer_memberName, Offer_branch, Offer_text, Offer_image, Offer_DateTime, Offer_minPrice, Offer_maxPrice, Offer_category, Offer_Username FROM Offer WHERE Offer_title = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $offerTitle);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt-> bind_result($token1, $token2,$token3,$token4,$token5,$token6, $token7, $token8, $token9, $token10); 

        while ( $stmt-> fetch() ) {
           $offer["offerMname"] = $offerMname;
           $offer["offerUname"] = $offerUname;
           $offer["offerTitle"] = $offerTitle;
           $offer["offerText"] = $offerText;
           $offer["offerBranch"] = $offerBranch;
           $offer["offerDateTime"] = $offerDateTime;
           $offer["offerMinPrice"] = $offerMinPrice;
           $offer["offerMaxPrice"] = $offerMaxPrice;
           $offer["offerCategory"] = $offerCategory;
           $offer["offerImageURL"] = $offerImageURL;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $offer;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

These are the LOC that the first error reported at fault:

```
        $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

        $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
        fclose($file);
```

The image in Android Studio is displayed just fine in the ImageView and it's also successfully encoded into using base64. The way i know the error is from php is because i tried to send a request using Postman and these errors popped up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're binding the variable `$mainpath`, but that variable is undefined in your script.

Comment: yup i already fixed that in myscript but forgot to update it the local version. Sorry!

Comment: The error is still displaying though.

Comment: `images taken from Android Studio (from the user's gallery),` ??? Didnt know that Android Studio had a users gallery. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I meant the image the user chooses from the gallery of their device retrieved through android studio code.